# Hide Javascript or CSS with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, plugins

I am a complete newbie when it comes to JS. I actually paid someone to write some JS for me but I need to tweak some stuff and I don't feel like hiring another person for just a few tweaks so I come to you for help.

The first issue is a wordpress plugin called Heads Up Bar. So fist thing I do is launch up the developer tools within Chrome and locate where its called on. I come across this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var data = {
    action: 'ehu_show_bar',
    home: ehu_is_home_pg
};
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    jQuery('body').prepend(response);
    if(ehu_animate === 'toggle'){
      jQuery('#ehu_bar').css('display', 'none');
      jQuery('#ehu_bar').slideToggle('fast');
    }

});
```

then I went and looked at the JS he created which looks a little like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#header').hide();
            jQuery('#sidebar').hide();
            jQuery('.main_navi').hide();
            jQuery('.category_navi_outer').hide();
            jQuery('.home_banner').hide();
            jQuery('.breadcrumb').hide();
```

So I create a new line called

```
jQuery('#ehu_bar').hide();
```

thinking it would be so easy. Obviously it didn't work. What am I missing? This plugin appears on every page of the site but sometimes its limited to only the homepage. What do I have to do now?

The next thing I need to hide is a JS from google ads. This appears in *almost* every post within wordpress but not in the homepage. I know the name of the JS, meaning I know what the file is called:

show_ads.js

and it is located in the product_detail.php file. What will it take to hide this google ad using JS?

Like I said, I am a bit new to this but I learn quickly. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Where did you create that new line? In the `.ready(...` block?

Comment: Also, consider opening a second question for the Google Ad Javascript issue.

Comment: You never really specify what you want to do with the Heads Up Bar... what specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter to the `jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, ...` is a method that is called when the AJAX request is finished. It will take a few milliseconds from when the page loads to do the AJAX request, so the order of what will actually happen is:

```
jQuery('#ehu_bar').hide(); // from jQuery(document).ready(..
```

Then a few milliseconds later:

```
jQuery('#ehu_bar').slideToggle('fast'); // from ajax callback
// This line effectively is like calling jQuery('#ehu_bar').show() but with an animation
```

Comment out the `slideToggle` line and you should be OK.